# Laravel rota acessível por dois tipos de usuário

Tags: laravel

Tenho uma aplicação onde tenho dois tipos de usuário autenticado (comum e administrador). Tenho uma rota onde passo o id do estado e me retorna um json com as cidades do tal estado. Acontece que gostaria de manter essa rota disponível apenas para usuários logados mas para os dois tipos.

```
Route::get('{id}/cities', 'ApiControllers\StateController@cities')
->middleware('auth:admin', 'auth', 'verified')->name('cities');
```

Deixei meu arquivo de rotas assim. Quando acesso com um usuário comum, sou direcionado pra tela de login de admins. Como faço para que ela seja acessível por qualquer usuário logado (independente do tipo)?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar as suas roles separadas por vírgula e atualizar o middleware pra receber corretamente os parâmetros.

```php
Route::get('{id}/cities', 'ApiControllers\StateController@cities')
->middleware('auth:admin,verified')->name('cities');
```

E no seu middleware, algo como:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ... $roles)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) 
        return redirect('login');

    $user = Auth::user();

    foreach($roles as $role) {
        if($user->hasRole($role))
            return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('login');
}
```

Referência:

https://pakainfo.com/laravel-middleware-multiple-roles-parameters/

Comment: Olá @capaci, obrigado pela resposta mas não foi exatamente sobre isso que perguntei. Talvez não tenha sido claro na minhas questão. Gostaria de saber como uma rota protegida por autenticação (login) pode ser acessado por usuários autenticados por guards diferentes. Vou alterar minha pergunta e ser mais específico.

Comment: acabei resolvendo apenas criando mais uma rota usando o mesmo trecho e mudando os guards em cada. Desculpe tomar seu tempo com uma pergunta tão infantil dessas.

Comment: Imagina, cara. Nenhuma pergunta é infantil. Não sei qual o melhor jeito, mas se resolveu seu problema, manda bala ;)