# Middleware no laravel para verificar se o usuario pertence a um grupo

Tags: php, laravel, active-directory, middleware

Bom dia e meu primeiro post aqui, estou querendo criar uma verificação no laravel para verificar se o usuário logado pertence ao grupo ex: TI, DIRETORIA, ADMINISTRAÇÂO etc. eu já faço a verificação na rota se o usuário esta logado usando o auth, eu queria uma segunda verificação:

```
Route::group(['middlewere' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'ti'], function(){

    Route::get('/listati', 'TiController@index')->name('index');

});
```

só poderia acessar essa rota que o usuário for do grupo da TI, o meu sistema utiliza o adldap2 e faz a sincronização com o AD, eu ate vi sobre fazer um novo middleware e verificar se o usuário pertence ao grupo, mas depois analisando eu teria que fazer uns 20 middleware para chegar se o usuário pertence ao grupo determinado, exemplo:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
     
use Closure;   

class Verificagrupo { 

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
 
     if ( !auth()->check() )
         return redirect()->route('login');
 
     $setor = auth()->user()->setor;
  
     if ( $setor != 'ti' )
         return redirect->route('naoautorizado');
  
     return $next($request); 
  }  
}
```

esse middleware só conseguiria verificar se o usuário e da ti, eu gostaria de verificar não só para o grupo da TI, mas também para ADM,SAUDE,ENGENHARIA etc todos os grupos... alguém tem alguma ideia ? de como melhorar essa verificação de grupo do usuario ? poderiam me dar uma luz indicar alguma biblioteca ou algo? e evitar de ter q criar 20 middleware para fazer essa verificação do grupo ? desde já agradeço...

Comment: Há essa biblioteca aqui, ela é bem completa:
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction

Comment: vou pesquisar sobre essa biblioteca amigo, obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um parâmetro no middleware [conforme a documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-parameters):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $setorPermitido)
{
     if ( !auth()->check() )
         return redirect()->route('login');
 
     $setor = auth()->user()->setor;
  
     if ( $setor != $setorPermitido )
         return redirect->route('naoautorizado');
  
     return $next($request); 
}
```

Após mapear o nome do middleware na variável `$routeMiddleware` do arquivo Kernel.php você pode usar nas rotas algo parecido com:

```
Route::group(['middlewere' => ['auth', 'verificagrupo:ti']], function(){
    // ...
});
```

Há uma [resposta parecida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372281/13561) mas não acho que seja uma pergunta duplicada.

Comment: amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda, eu tinha visto a documentação antes de voce responder, mas com a sua respota eu olhei novamente a documentação dessa vez em português e o que me faltava para evitar um monte de middleware era justamente isso pegar o parâmetro da rota... Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Bem fazendo desse método realmente irias precisar de muitas verificações e criar um *middleware* novo sempre que um novo grupo surgisse, uma solução para este problema seria agrupar os grupos (meio confuso)... da seguinte forma:

Imaginemos que terias uma tabela de **grupos** da seguinte forma:

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id |    nome    | grupo |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | ADM        |     1 |
|  2 | ENGENHARIA |     1 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

e Um Middleware exemplo:

```
class Verificagrupo { 

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
     if (!auth()->check())
        return redirect()->route('login');
        
    $setor = auth()->user()->setor;
    
    $grupos = Grupo::where('grupo', 1)
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
    
    // verificar se utilizador esta nos grupos com coluna grupo com valor 1
    if(!in_array($setor, $grupos)) {
        return redirect()->route('naoautorizado');
    }
  
     return $next($request); 
  }  
}
```

Assim verificavas tudo ao mesmo tempo, mas em alternativa a isto poderias utilizar um pacote que irá te ajudar bastante no desenvolvimento: [laravel-permissions](http://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction)

Comment: vou testar amigo, acabei ficando sem tempo no momento por causa de outra demanda, mas vou parar depois para ver direitinho, mesmo assim obrigado